# Sublime not working in Git Bash

Tags: windows, sublimetext3, msysgit

I'm on windows 7 and I can't figure out how to make my Git Bash run Sublime Text 3 when i enter `subl`.

My .exe is located in `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3`
git is in: `C:\msysgit\msysgit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3` directory to the windows PATH.
2. Do you really have `subl.exe` in `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3` folder? For Windows the default file name is `sublime_text.exe`